My Spring Boot project cannot start because it integrates Flink
My Spring Boot project cannot start because it integrates Flink! Prompt that the class cannot be found, but this class does exist, packaging is also available
Log
2024-05-29 10:02:19,750 INFO (AbstractBlobCache.java:251)- Shutting down BLOB cache
2024-05-29 10:02:19,748 ERROR (SpringApplication.java:859)- Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$6(SpringApplication.java:797)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:786)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at com.aiyuns.tinkerplay.TinkerPlayApplication.main(TinkerPlayApplication.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'mysql-cdc'.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2455)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2319)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2293)
    at com.aiyuns.tinkerplay.Listener.MysqlEventListener.run(MysqlEventListener.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$4(SpringApplication.java:786)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobInitializationException: Could not start the JobMaster.
    at org.apache.flink.util.ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ExceptionUtils.java:321)
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedFunction$2(FunctionUtils.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:646)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:483)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:387)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1312)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1843)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1808)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobInitializationException: Could not start the JobMaster.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultJobMasterServiceProcess.lambda$new$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceProcess.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1773)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1770)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig
    at org.apache.flink.util.ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ExceptionUtils.java:321)
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:114)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:78)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2061)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1927)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2252)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1762)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:540)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:539)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:527)
    at org.apache.flink.util.SerializedValue.deserializeValue(SerializedValue.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultSchedulerFactory.createInstance(DefaultSchedulerFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.createScheduler(DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createScheduler(JobMaster.java:379)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:356)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.internalCreateJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.lambda$createJobMasterService$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:112)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
2024-05-29 10:02:19,751 INFO (BlobServer.java:397)- Stopped BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:64666
2024-05-29 10:02:19,753 INFO (PekkoRpcService.java:435)- Stopped Pekko RPC service.

enter image description here
enter image description here
How can I solve this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

ClassLoader platformClassLoader = ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader();
ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
ClassLoader threadClassLoader =  Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
StreamExecutionEnvironment local = new StreamExecutionEnvironment((Configuration) env.getConfiguration(),threadClassLoader);
local.setParallelism(5);
DebeziumSourceFunction<DataInfo> localSqlSource = buildDataChangeSourceLocal();
DataStream<DataInfo> customSource = local
        .addSource(localSqlSource).name("local");
CustomSink customSink = new CustomSink();
customSink.setKey("local");
customSource.addSink(customSink);
JobClient jobClient = local.executeAsync("local-----------Job");

I tracked the code and found that this is an issue with the project's class loader. After running locally and packaging with Spring Boot, the class loader is different. The locally launched class loader is sun.misc Launcher $AppClassLoader, but after executing Java jar startup, the class loader is org.springframework.boot.loaderLaunchedURLClassLoader. This is because the Spring project has customized the class loader to load files and passes the class loader when called, passing the current thread's class loader in. According to the Spring parental delegation mechanism, it is certain that it cannot be queried. So I checked the constructor method of StreamExecutioneEnvironment and tried to construct a new object by passing it to the specified constructor, but I failed. I estimate that it did not fully execute successfully. I think this idea is not a problem, and the other way is to replace the default loader after Spring Boot starts with $Appclassloader.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
